# Connect tableau with Elastic search via Spark SQL

Tags: elasticsearch, hive, tableau-api, apache-spark-sql

I found a [post](http://ryrobes.com/systems/connecting-tableau-to-elasticsearch-read-how-to-query-elasticsearch-with-hive-sql-and-hadoop/) that discusses about connecting Tableau to Elastic Search via Hive SQL. I was wondering if there is a way to connect to Elastic Search via Spark SQL as I am not much familiar with hive.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

@NicholasY It got it resolved after a couple of trials. Two steps that I took:-

- I wasn't using the right driver for connection. I was using datastax enterprise driver. However, they have a driver for spark sql as well. I used windows 64bit version of driver. Using MapR Hadoop Hive and Hortonworks Hadoop Hive drivers didn't work as I've Apache hive.
- When I used right driver (from DataStax) I realized that my hive metastore and spark-thrift-server running on same port. I changed spark-thrift-server's port to 10001 and a successful connection was established.

**A new problem:** I've created external table in hive. I am able to query the data as well. I start hive-metastore as a service. However, as mentioned on this [link](https://hadoopi.wordpress.com/2014/12/31/spark-connect-tableau-desktop-to-sparksql/)  I am not able to see my tables in hive in Spark SQL. My connection of Tableau with Spark Sql is of no use unless I see tables from hive metastore!! When I do *show tables;* in spark sql (via spark-sql shell and hive metastore running as a service as same time), it runs a job which gives a completion time also but now table names. I monitored it via localhost:4040 I see that input and output size are 0.0. I believe I am not able to get tables from hive in spark sql that is why I don't see any table after connection is established from Tableau to spark sql.

**EDIT**
I changed metastore from derby to mysql for both hive and spark sql.

Answer (score 1):

@busybug91,

The right driver is [here](https://databricks.com/spark/odbc-driver-download) please try with this one. Could be solve your issue.

Comment: Yep. I downloaded this driver last week and I was able to connect to Spark SQL. However, I couldn't see any tables.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to do that, so maybe i can help you to warn up something.

First, compile a Spark SQL version with Hive and thrift Server (ver 0.13):

`export MAVEN_OPTS="-Xmx2g -XX:MaxPermSize=512M -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=512m"`

`mvn -Pyarn -Phadoop-2.4 -Dhadoop.version=2.4.0 -Phive -Phive-thriftserver -DskipTests clean package`

You need to have a hive-site.xml properly configurered to work with Hive and to copy it to spark/conf folder.

Then, you have to set the $CLASSPATH with the elasticsearch-hadoop jar path.

Be careful ! Spark SQL 1.2.0 is not working with elasticsearch-hadoop-2.0.x. You have to use a elasticsearch-hadoop-2.1.0-Beta4 or BUILD-SNAPSHOT available [here](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-hadoop/).

To finish you have to run thriftserver with something like that:

`./start-thriftserver.sh --master spark://master:7077 --driver-class-path $CLASSPATH --jars /root/spark-sql/spark-1.2.0/lib/elasticsearch-hadoop-2.1.0.Beta4.jar --hiveconf hive.server2.thrift.bind.host 0.0.0.0 --hiveconf hive.server2.thrift.port 10000`

It works for me but only on small docType ( 5000 rows ) , the data-colocation seems not working. I looking for a solution to move elasticsearch-hadoop.jar on each Spark workers as [ryrobes](http://ryrobes.com/systems/connecting-tableau-to-elasticsearch-read-how-to-query-elasticsearch-with-hive-sql-and-hadoop/) did for Hadoop.

If you find a way to locate access to elasticsearch, let me know ;)

HTH,

Comment: I have configures my hive to run with MySQL metastore. I've created an external table also in hive. Classpath set to mySql connecter and elasticsearch-hadoop snapshot jar. Copied same hive configuration to SPARK_HOME/conf. 
Build spark with -Phive and -Phive-thriftserver. Simba Spark SQL driver installed on VM. Using tableau's connect to other  database (ODBC) to connect to spark thrift server. Spark server, thirft-server and elastic search all are running. I am still not able to connect to it. Can you provide more details as what may be wrong.

Comment: What is the error message catch return by Tableau and Spark ? Did you create a table on your metastore to map with ES ? `CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE mytable ( value type, ... ) STORED BY 'org.elasticsearch.hadoop.hive.EsStorageHandler' TBLPROPERTIES('es.resource' = 'index/doctype','es.nodes' = 'node1','es.port' = '9200','es.query' = '?q=*');`

Comment: It got resolved after a couple of trials. I wasn't using the right driver for connection. When I used right driver (from DataStax) I realized that my hive metastore and spark-thrift-server running on same port. I change spark-thrift-server's port to 10001 and a successful connection was established.

Comment: @Nicholas Where did you create this table. I created mine in Hive but I am not able to see that table in spark.

Comment: @busybug91 You can create it from Spark SQL Shell for example or from Hive Shell.

Comment: I created external table in Spark SQL with same syntax as in hive. I didn't use column mappings via 'es.mapping.names' = 'date:@timestamp , url:url_123 '). I just kept the attribute names in external table same to properties of type in elastic search. I used datatype mapping from elastic search to spark sql as mentioned on bottom of this page: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/current/hive.html.  However, I am getting null values for some string attributes in spark sql while other string attributes have values. Any idea about that?

Comment: Could you send me your CREATE query ?

Comment: CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE tableName (birthDate timestamp, dmAsp string, dmBpD string, dmBpS string, dmC string, dmHba1cDate timestamp, dmHba1cT bigint, dmH string, dmI string, dmLdlcT string, dmLdlcValue string, dmRecentBp bigint, dmTobacco string, gender string, ohaPd string, firstName string,  lastName string, pctobaccoscreen string) STORED BY 'org.elasticsearch.hadoop.hive.EsStorageHandler' TBLPROPERTIES('es.resource' = 'index/type', 'es.nodes' = 'localhost','es.port' = '9200','es.query' = '?q=*');